# Not getting latest value from textBox

Tags: javascript, jquery, textbox, coffeescript

I am trying to implement the following in coffeescript/jquery

-> When user is typing, check that if the textBox is empty (or has text "Write a comment..."), hide the 'add comment' button. Else show the 'add comment' button

[image]

[image]

However, I am facing the issue whereby the val() returned to me from the textbox is always one keystroke behind.

For example, if I type 'sad' in the box, the target.val() returns me only 'sa'.

[image]

How do I get the most updated value in the text box as I type?

My implementation as below

```
events:
  "keydown .comment_area": "commenting"

commenting: (e) ->
  target = @$(e.currentTarget)

  //target.val() is not returning me the latest character entered in the box
  if $.trim(target.val()) == "" or $.trim(target.val()) =="Write a comment..."
    //hide the 'add' button
    @$('.add_comment').hide()
  else
    //show the 'add' button
    @$('.add_comment').show()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bind to the `keyup` event instead of `keydown`.

See the [keyboard event order](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#events-keyboard-event-order).

Comment: You could also bind to the [change](http://api.jquery.com/change/) event. If you don't care about the key(s) that were pressed to produce the change, that's probably best. (Consider that right-clicking and selecting "Paste" will modify the textBox's value without a `keydown` or `keyup`, for example.) [**Edit:** Whoops, nm, change events only fire on `blur`, which won't do what you want.)

Comment: Amending my previous comment: A better solution would be this [jQuery Text Change Event plugin](http://www.zurb.com/playground/jquery-text-change-custom-event).

Comment: why not use keypress instead of keyup?

Answer (score 0):

Use either `keyup` or `keypress` event: `keydown` fires before the computer has actually placed the character within the text box, whereas the other two fire after that happens: `keypress` right after, and `keyup` when the key is physically lifted up. `keypress`, I think, fires for each character inserted into the textbox (i.e., when you press and hold and the character repeats, it fires separately), whereas `keyup` only fires after the key is lifted, so if you were to press and hold a key, it would only fire after that key is lifted, not for every character inserted.

BTW, in coffeescript, parentheses aren't necessary for function calls -- only when you aren't passing in any arguments. For example:

`@$(e.currentTarget)` -> `@$ e.currentTarget`

`$.trim(target.val())` -> `$.trim target.val()`

Also, I noticed sometimes you reference `$` with `@`, whereas sometimes you're using the global jQuery -- is there any reason for this? It seems that it should be consistent.